# Why does the return rate of a game appear to vary when output by two different programs?

Tags: c#, winforms, debugging, logic, simulation

I have coded two C# programs, which use two different approaches to evaluate the outcome of a certain casino-style game (casino-style in the sense that the user pays points to take a turn, and sometimes receives points as a reward depending on that turn’s result).  Program 1 calculates the average profitability of the best game play decision for each possible game state, starting at a round's end and working to the beginning.  The average profitability of the starting game state is equivalent to, thus can be used to infer, the average profitability of the game as a whole.  Program 1 also outputs a proper strategy for the game.

Program 2 accepts a strategy as input (I use the same strategy generated by Program 1), and simulates actual beginning-to-end game play using that strategy, cycling through many iterations of the game to gather statistics.  This program outputs the return rate of the game based on the simulated trials (100% being breakeven).

**Desired behavior:** To produce correct and non-contradictory results in Program 1’s gamePlay.value variable for the starting game state (representing the game’s profitability in points), and Program 2’s returnRate variable (representing the game’s return rate).

**Specific problem:** Program 1’s gamePlay.value variable for the starting game state (Colorless, Colorless, Colorless) outputs 51.025 when the user inputs the same starting parameters as those which are hard-coded into Program 2 (namely, cost = 51 and baseBet = 50).  A secondary task of Program 1 is to calculate the average number of turns remaining in the round, for each possible game state.  Again, by noting this value for the starting state, the average number of turns in the round as a whole is known.  There are, on average, 4.246 turns per round.  By multiplying this number by the cost per turn, 51, we see that the average cost per round is 216.546.  Adding the 51.025 profit yields 267.571, and dividing this number by the cost per round reveals a 123.563% return rate for the game.

This is not what Program 2 calculates, even using an extremely large number of game play samples.  Some output samples, each of which are the result of one million game play turns, include:

1.00978242220553
1.00976014965254
1.00977590536083
1.0098289475708
1.00979315220468

123.563% and 100.98% are very far from each other.

**Code to reproduce problem:**

PROGRAM 1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace theBlindPainterAnalyzerSimplified
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        double cost;
        double baseBet;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void calculateStrategyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  // This is the primary code, analogous to main()
        {
            cost = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
            baseBet = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
            GameState[] gameStates = new GameState[10];

            for (int h = 0; h < gameStates.Length; h++)
            {
                gameStates[h] = new GameState();
            }

            int i = 0;
            foreach (var c in BuildCombinations(Enum.GetValues(typeof(OrderedColors)).Cast<OrderedColors>().Reverse().ToArray(), 3))
            {
                int j = 0;
                foreach (var panel in c)
                {
                    gameStates[i].colors[j] = panel;
                    j++;
                }

                i++;
            }

            foreach (var gameState in gameStates)  // Stores the expected value of each decision from each game state
            {
                int numPreviousStrokes = 0;

                for (int j = 0; j < gameState.colors.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (gameState.colors[j] == OrderedColors.Purple)
                    {
                        numPreviousStrokes++;
                    }
                    else if (gameState.colors[j] == OrderedColors.Blue)
                    {
                        numPreviousStrokes += 2;
                    }
                }

                double zeroProfitability = 0;
                double oneProfitability = checkProfitability(gameState, 1, gameStates);
                double twoProfitability = -4;
                double threeProfitability = -4;

                if (numPreviousStrokes >= 2)
                {
                    twoProfitability = checkProfitability(gameState, 2, gameStates);
                }

                if (numPreviousStrokes >= 3)
                {
                    threeProfitability = checkProfitability(gameState, 3, gameStates);
                }

                if (zeroProfitability > oneProfitability && zeroProfitability > twoProfitability && zeroProfitability > threeProfitability)
                {
                    gameState.optimalPlay = 0;
                    gameState.value = zeroProfitability;

                }
                else if (oneProfitability > zeroProfitability && oneProfitability > twoProfitability && oneProfitability > threeProfitability)
                {
                    gameState.optimalPlay = 1;
                    gameState.value = oneProfitability;
                }
                else if (twoProfitability > zeroProfitability && twoProfitability > oneProfitability && twoProfitability > threeProfitability)
                {
                    gameState.optimalPlay = 2;
                    gameState.value = twoProfitability;
                }
                else if (threeProfitability > zeroProfitability && threeProfitability > oneProfitability && threeProfitability > twoProfitability)
                {
                    gameState.optimalPlay = 3;
                    gameState.value = threeProfitability;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Draw!");
                }

                gameState.remainingTurnCount = checkRemainingTurnCount(gameState, gameStates);

                richTextBox1.Text += gameState.colors[0] + "," + gameState.colors[1] + "," + gameState.colors[2] + "," + gameState.optimalPlay + "," + gameState.value + "," + gameState.remainingTurnCount + "\n";
            }
        }

        private double checkProfitability(GameState state, int numStrokes, GameState[] gameStates)  // Calculates the expected value of making a particular decision from a particular game state
        {
            double[] possiblePayoffs = new double[50000];
            int pPIndex = 0;
            double sumOfPossiblePayoffs = 0;
            double averagePayoff = 0;

            double payoff = -cost;

            for (int i = 0; i < Math.Pow(3, numStrokes); i++)
            {
                int innerForIndex = i;
                for (int j = 0; j < numStrokes; j++)
                {
                    state.colors[innerForIndex % 3]++;
                    innerForIndex /= 3;
                }

                if ((int)state.colors[0] <= 2 && (int)state.colors[1] <= 2 && (int)state.colors[2] <= 2)
                {
                    int numPurple = 0;
                    int numBlue = 0;

                    int numNonZeros = 0;

                    for (int panel = 0; panel <= 2; panel++)
                    {
                        if (state.colors[panel] == OrderedColors.Purple)
                        {
                            numPurple++;
                        }

                        if (state.colors[panel] == OrderedColors.Blue)
                        {
                            numBlue++;
                        }
                    }

                    if (numPurple != 0)
                    {
                        numNonZeros++;
                    }

                    if (numBlue != 0)
                    {
                        numNonZeros++;
                    }

                    switch (numPurple)
                    {
                        case 2:
                            payoff += (.7 * baseBet);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            payoff += (2 * baseBet);
                            break;
                    }

                    switch (numBlue)
                    {
                        case 2:
                            payoff += baseBet;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            payoff += (4.12 * baseBet);
                            break;
                    }

                    if (numPurple + numBlue == 3 && numPurple != 0 && numBlue != 0)
                    {
                        payoff += (4 * baseBet);
                    }
                }

                OrderedColors[] currentColors = (OrderedColors[])state.colors.Clone();  // Temporary clone of array used to find corrosponding game state
                Array.Sort(currentColors);
                Array.Reverse(currentColors);

                foreach (var gameState in gameStates)
                {
                    if (areArraysEqual(gameState.colors, currentColors))
                    {
                        payoff += gameState.value;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                possiblePayoffs[pPIndex] = payoff;
                pPIndex++;
                payoff = -cost;

                innerForIndex = i;
                for (int j = 0; j < numStrokes; j++)
                {
                    state.colors[innerForIndex % 3]--;
                    innerForIndex /= 3;
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i <= pPIndex; i++)
            {
                sumOfPossiblePayoffs += possiblePayoffs[i];
            }

            averagePayoff = sumOfPossiblePayoffs / pPIndex;

            return averagePayoff;
        }

        private double checkRemainingTurnCount(GameState state, GameState[] gameStates)
        {
            double[] possibleTurnAverages = new double[50000];
            int pTAIndex = 0;
            double sumOfPossibleTurnAverages = 0;
            double turns = -4;

            if (state.optimalPlay == 0)
            {
                turns = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Math.Pow(3, state.optimalPlay); i++)
                {
                    int innerForIndex = i;
                    for (int j = 0; j < state.optimalPlay; j++)
                    {
                        state.colors[innerForIndex % 3]++;
                        innerForIndex /= 3;
                    }

                    if ((int)state.colors[0] <= 3 && (int)state.colors[1] <= 3 && (int)state.colors[2] <= 3)
                    {
                        OrderedColors[] currentColors = (OrderedColors[])state.colors.Clone();  // Temporary clone of array used to find corrosponding game state
                        Array.Sort(currentColors);
                        Array.Reverse(currentColors);

                        foreach (var gameState in gameStates)
                        {
                            if (areArraysEqual(gameState.colors, currentColors))
                            {
                                possibleTurnAverages[pTAIndex] = gameState.remainingTurnCount + 1;
                                pTAIndex++;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        possibleTurnAverages[i] = 1;
                        pTAIndex++;
                    }

                    innerForIndex = i;
                    for (int j = 0; j < state.optimalPlay; j++)
                    {
                        state.colors[innerForIndex % 3]--;
                        innerForIndex /= 3;
                    }
                }

                for (int i = 0; i <= pTAIndex; i++)
                {
                    sumOfPossibleTurnAverages += possibleTurnAverages[i];
                }

                turns = sumOfPossibleTurnAverages / pTAIndex;
            }

            return turns;
        }

        private static IEnumerable<T[]> BuildCombinations<T>(T[] items, int itemsCountInCombination, int startIndex = 0)  // Finds all possible unique game states; I did not write this code myself
        {
            if (itemsCountInCombination == 0)
            {
                yield return new T[0];
                yield break;
            }

            for (int i = startIndex; i < items.Length; i++)
            {
                foreach (var combination in BuildCombinations(items, itemsCountInCombination - 1, i))
                {
                    var c = new T[itemsCountInCombination];
                    c[0] = items[i];
                    Array.Copy(combination, 0, c, 1, combination.Length);
                    yield return c;
                }
            }
        }

        private bool areArraysEqual<T>(T[] array1, T[] array2)
        {
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(array1, array2))
            {
                return true;
            }

            if (array1.Length != array2.Length)
            {
                return false;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
            {
                if (array1[i].Equals(array2[i]) == false)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    }

    public class GameState
    {
        public OrderedColors[] colors = { OrderedColors.Colorless, OrderedColors.Colorless, OrderedColors.Colorless };
        public int optimalPlay = -4;  // The value 0 has a specific meaning
        public double value = 0;
        public double remainingTurnCount;
    }

    public enum OrderedColors
    {
        Colorless,
        Purple,
        Blue
    }
}
```

__

PROGRAM 2

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace theBlindPainterTesterContinuousSimplified
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Random rn1_3 = new Random();
        float cost = 51;
        float baseBet = 50;
        static double startScore = 100000;
        static double score = startScore;
        int cycledPoints = 0;
        double returnRate = 0;
        bool isRoundOver = false;

        OrderedColors[] panelColors = { OrderedColors.Colorless, OrderedColors.Colorless, OrderedColors.Colorless };

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string strategyFileText;

            using (StreamReader strategyFile = new StreamReader("strategy.txt"))
            {
                strategyFileText = strategyFile.ReadToEnd();
            }

            string[] strats = strategyFileText.Split('\n');

            for (int h = 0; h < 1000000; h++)
            {
                isRoundOver = false;

                int selectedPlay = selectPlay(strats);

                if (selectedPlay == 0)
                {
                    endRound();
                }
                else if (selectedPlay >= 1 && selectedPlay <= 3)
                {
                    score = score - cost;
                    cycledPoints += Convert.ToInt32(cost);

                    for (int i = 0; i < selectedPlay; i++)
                    {
                        if (isRoundOver == false)
                        {
                            paintPanel();
                        }
                    }

                    payOut();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(selectedPlay + " is not a valid play.");
                }
            }

            if (startScore != 0 && cycledPoints != 0)
            {
                returnRate = Math.Pow(score / startScore, startScore / cycledPoints);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Division by zero error.");
            }

            richTextBox1.Text = returnRate.ToString();
        }

        // Retrieves the appropriate game play for the current panel colors
        private int selectPlay(string[] strats)
        {
            int play = -4; // The value 0 has a specific meaning

            Array.Sort(panelColors);
            Array.Reverse(panelColors);

            foreach (string strat in strats)
            {
                string[] stratComponents = strat.Split(',');
                int matches = 0;

                for (int j = 0; j <= 2; j++)
                {
                    if (stratComponents[j] == panelColors[j].ToString())
                    {
                        matches++;
                    }
                }

                if (matches == 3)
                {
                    play = Convert.ToInt32(stratComponents[3]);
                    break;
                }
            }

            return play;
        }

        // Paints a single randomly selected panel
        private void paintPanel()
        {
            int primedPanel = rn1_3.Next(1, 4);

            if (panelColors[primedPanel - 1] == OrderedColors.Colorless)
            {
                panelColors[primedPanel - 1] = OrderedColors.Purple;
            }
            else if (panelColors[primedPanel - 1] == OrderedColors.Purple)
            {
                panelColors[primedPanel - 1] = OrderedColors.Blue;
            }
            else if (panelColors[primedPanel - 1] == OrderedColors.Blue)
            {
                endRound();
            }
        }

        // Adjusts score and takes action if the game is over
        private void payOut()
        {
            int numPurple = 0;
            int numBlue = 0;

            int numNonZeros = 0;

            for (int panel = 0; panel <= 2; panel++)
            {
                if (panelColors[panel] == OrderedColors.Purple)
                {
                    numPurple++;
                }

                if (panelColors[panel] == OrderedColors.Blue)
                {
                    numBlue++;
                }
            }

            if (numPurple != 0)
            {
                numNonZeros++;
            }

            if (numBlue != 0)
            {
                numNonZeros++;
            }

            switch (numPurple)
            {
                case 2:
                    score += (.7 * baseBet);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    score += (2 * baseBet);
                    break;
            }

            switch (numBlue)
            {
                case 2:
                    score += baseBet;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    score += (4.12 * baseBet);
                    break;
            }

            if (numPurple + numBlue == 3 && numPurple != 0 && numBlue != 0)
            {
                score += (4 * baseBet);
            }
        }

        private void endRound()
        {
            isRoundOver = true;

            for (int panel = 0; panel <= 2; panel++)
            {
                panelColors[panel] = OrderedColors.Colorless;
            }
        }
    }

    public enum OrderedColors
    {
        Colorless,
        Purple,
        Blue
    }
}
```

__

**What I Have Considered:**  The possible types of problems I have tried to categorize this as are programming logic errors, snowballing rounding errors, and casting errors.  It is difficult to isolate the error(s) because Program 1 solves the game using backward induction, while Program 2 gathers information by playing the game start to finish many times, two fundamentally different approaches.  I have spent a fairly substantial amount of time with Program 1 in the debugger, including working out the results for the last few game states on paper, and it seems to be functioning properly and to a very respectable precision, as far as I can tell.  Program 2 is more difficult to do this with due to the inclusion of randomness in the game, but I have stepped through a small number of iterations and the calculations seem to me to be on point.
Can anyone clarify the reason that these two approaches to return rate calculation produce conflicting results?

**The game (this is detailed info about the game being studied, feel free to skip this section):**  This game consists of three objects called panels, which the user paints.  Each panel starts out Colorless.  At first, the user must select 1, which paints one random panel.  A Colorless panel will turn Purple when painted.  A Purple panel will turn Blue when painted again.  A Blue panel, when painted again, will immediately cause all panels to return to Colorless, and a new round begins.  Once the user has painted a panel, he/she can, on the next turn, select 1 or 2, which will paint one random panel, or two random panels, respectively.  Once two units of paint have been applied, the user can select 1, 2, or 3, and the appropriate result is applied.  When a new round begins, only option 1 is available until 2 and 3 are unlocked again.

Each turn costs 51 points, regardless of whether 1, 2, or 3 is selected.  There is a payout table, as laid out in the code, which may award points back to the user based on the resulting state of the panels.  The user can also decide to start a new round at any time, and revert all panels to Colorless, which does not have a cost.  The goal of the game is to earn rather than lose points, on average.

Below are my project folders, in case someone wishes to compile, as the interface is not contained in the above code.

http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=geb5da551f035649699958123114d58733569b2fb4

Comment: The character limit is for a purpose here. Your question is too large. You really need to narrow down the problem.

Comment: The relevant line from pastebin: `int primedPanel = rn1_6.Next(1, 7);`

Comment: @BartoszKP Heya, I've tried to do that as much as possible, but the problem is that one technique approaches the game start to finish, and the other finish to start, so I've failed to make further progress on isolation the error.  Any tips for narrowing?

Comment: @Henk Holterman All of the research I've done suggests that this is the best way to produce random numbers.  Are you saying the the random number generation could be the problem?

Comment: Sorry, this wall of text is incomprehensible for my attention span ;)

Comment: You're unlikely to get much help here.  Not only that, but despite the code dump I'm not sure if you are giving enough information!  You say you are evaluating `a certain casino-style game` but you don't seem to tell us WHAT game.  How can we know which of your two programs is correct if we don't know what you are simulating?

Comment: @BartoszKP Sorry to hear that.  I've had issues with my questions not being clear enough in the past, so I wanted to really hammer out the problem according to the Web site's suggestions.  I realize it may be a bit long winded to read.  I also realize the code is long, but I didn't want to snip there, as anything I would try to remove would change the functionality.

Comment: @GoldenDragon Good point, I've added the game to the question.

Comment: The use of Random looks OK, I should have added that there are no Threads/Tasks involved. First thing people will want to know/check.

Comment: You have 6 colors and 4 cases per color. How about you pare it down to 2 colors and 2 cases per color, probably end up with ¹/10 the amount of code and surely the discrepancy will still manifest

Comment: @Schollii Very nice suggestion, I'll work on doing just that when I have time to perform an overhaul of both programs (prob will be a few days to a week), if no one jumps in with a solution by then.

Comment: The code has been simplified as suggested.  There are now only two colors + Colorless, and two cases per color.  I also reduced the number of panels to three.

Comment: you should write a book about this

Comment: @HamidP I'm not sure how to interpret that.  =P